# Flutter texture with gstreamer on Linux

Tags: linux, flutter, opengl, textures, gstreamer

I’m trying to create an app on Linux that uses gstreamer to render a udp h265 stream to texture and embed it to flutter app with its texture api or platformview. But I’m struggling to figure out how to make it work.

Does anyone has some advice on it.

Comment: hi, I'm facing almost same issue. Could you solve it?

Comment: I've solved it using the texture support on Linux, please refer to https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/24916 on github.

Comment: This is working, but only on flutter 1.x and 3.0.0, for some reason not works on 2.x wasted weeks.